# Problem with arming power - Stäubli CS8 with RX60B - L

Tags: robotic-arm, industrial-robot

we are having a problem with setting up Stäubli CS8 controller with RX60B-L arm,

our company bought the arm and controller several years ago, and only now we have an actual use for it and we are trying to set it up.

There was a few problems that I had dealt with,

firstly a discharged battery, which was no problem to replace, secondly the connector at the working mode selector was damaged also an easy fix.

But I am not able to power-up the arm. When I try to power up the arm, the controller refuses: Arm power enable request refused: cabinet working mode is remote or invalid. Also the working mode status LEDs on the teach pendant do not light up at all, according to manual and online videos the working mode status LEDs are supposed to light up accroding to the mode selected on the working mode selector box.

Also after a start up there's an error message: Internal error on fieldbus Board=1 Equipment=0 Channel=0 Status=33

Another errors:
Internal error DRIVE NoDriveConfiguration 1
Internal error DRIVE NoDriveConfiguration 2
Internal error DRIVE NoDriveConfiguration 3
Internal error DRIVE NoDriveConfiguration 4
Internal error DRIVE NoDriveConfiguration 5
Internal error DRIVE NoDriveConfiguration 6

Which i guess collerate to the axis drivers, Is it possible to restore the configurations or something?

I already restored the positions in the callibration menu, but that didn't fix the problem.

How do I fix this problem ? Can there still be problem in the wms box ?

Best regards
[image: Error log after startup]

[image: Error log]

[image: Pendant and WMS control box]

Comment: Photos: https://imgur.com/a/qoi2FqW

Comment: Please [edit] and upload and add any photos to the question. People are more likely to view them in the question than having to click a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a solution:

Firtsly I connected to the robot filesystem using FTP

Secondly I uploaded the arm.cfx from CD to the usr/configuration folder

In the arm.cfx there were no information about the order number and arm type

Finally after a restart of the CS8 controller the Drive errors dissapeared and the hand symbol lighted up on the teach pendant accordingly to the WMS box selected mode.

I'll test if it is possible to move the arm and after that I'll close the thread.
Thanks for help.

The old arm.cfx file header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<arm>
  <String name="date" value="20 AUG 2006  20:21" />
  <String name="orderNumber" value="" />
  <String name="arm" value="" />
  <String name="tuning" value="" />|
  <String name="mount" value="floor" />
```

Comment: Please paste code as text and not as a screen shot. Images are not text-searchable.

Answer (score 0):

The fieldbus error will not affect the robot booting up or moving. The CS8 used optional fieldbus PCI cards from Applicom / Molex (Molex purchased Applicom and rebranded the boards) The error 33 means it is not correctly configured.

The errors with the drive configuration is causing the working mode to be set to invalid. The most likely cause is either a corrupt arm.cfx file in the usr/configs folder or a missing or corrupt system.zfx file in the sys/ partition.

You can contact Staubli tech support for you region. There is normally a label of the controller with contact information. For the USA it would be 864 486 5429.